# Record audio with AudioRecord doesn't work

Tags: android, phone-call, recorder

I am using AudioRecord to record audio during a phone call, and I'm using this method (AudioRecord) because the app needs to analyze the data during the phone call. The problem here is that in some devices I get the result that I want, but in other devices the application just crash. These are my configuration parameters:

```
public static int frequency = 16000;
public static int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
public static int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
public static int bufferSize;
```

...

```
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
```

***1- If I use: MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL***

The app doesn't work with any device, and usually I can see this error in logs:
     "Could not get audio input for record source 4"

***2- If I use: MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC***

The app works but just with some devices. In other devices doesn't work at all and I can't see any error.

***3- I also tried with:***

- MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK
- MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK
- MediaRecorder.AudioSource.COMMUNICATION

Without results.

**Do you have any idea of why the app is working just with "MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC" during phone calls? And why it is working just with some devices?**

Comment: Please paste your code snippets.